# How to delete the rows that contain string?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to replace a string in sql script. Im using this query

```
update [master].[dbo].[Test]
set Student_ID = REPLACE (Student_ID , '1|2_', '1|2_345_')
```

I think my query is correct but im getting this error "String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated"
I think this is happen because in column Student_ID have redundant data like "hdhvjf124rgrthrt". How to delete the rows that contain "hdhvjf124rgrthrt" stuffs?

Comment: alireza_s_84 is right,check the column datalength

Comment: i change it from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(max) and it's working. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

**"String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated"**

> This exception is usually means that your db field doesn't have enough
>   length.

I think after you replace string, result string length is larger than column data length. try change column size and run script again.

Comment: i change it from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(max) and it's working. thank you so much

Comment: the sql server error message is helpful and right to known

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update [master].[dbo].[Test]
set Student_ID = REPLACE (Student_ID , '1|2_', '1|2_345_')
WHERE Student_ID  like '%' + '1|2_' + '%'
```

Comment: it still giving me error "String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete those records with:

```
DELETE FROM [master].[dbo].[Test]
WHERE  Student_ID LIKE '%hdhvjf124rgrthrt%'
```

I don't think that's the problem though. I think the length of `Student_ID` is too short when you do the replace (since you are adding characters). What is the length of `Student_ID` and how long are the actual values of `Student_ID`?

Comment: lenght of my Student_ID is nvarchar (255)

Comment: And how long are the actual Student_ID values? Can you give some samples?

Comment: i change it from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(max) and it's working. thank you so much

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good choice for an ID field, which one would assume is a prinmary key.

Comment: What student ID needs more than 255 characters? My old student ID was not longer than 10

Answer (score 0):

You must have some data that already has a length of 252 or more.
Thus when you replace '1|2_' with '1|2_345_' you are pushing it over the 255 length as you are adding 4 extra characters, or more if more that one occurance of the old pattern exists.

Try running a query to see....

```
SELECT LEN(StudentId) FROM TEST ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

That's your problem truncation wise.

However, you have asked how to do the DELETE and @HoneyBadger has already shown you that.